# Scroll panel in ASP.NET down

Tags: c#, asp.net, scroll, panel

I have a page with a panel (class System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel) in ASP.NET. The panel in updating each 4 seconds and so it scrolls up every time. Can you say me please how to scroll it programmatically down?

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="500">
                                           </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: are you using ajax to refresh the panel's content?

Comment: I'm using Repeater and when I change it's DataSourceID it refreshs